# Porter Stemming in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, text-processing, stemming, porter-stemmer

Recently i was working on application to do some text processing like stemming, and i found stemming Porter in c# code in this link : http://snowball.tartarus.org/otherlangs/english_cpp.txt

I've tried to run but anything change with the text. i try to call the stemming class, like this:

```
string inputstem = File.ReadAllText(textBox21.Text);
Porter2 stemmer = new Porter2();
string outputstem = stemmer.stem(inputstem);
textBoxfile.Text = outputstem;
```

i can't get the result correctly .. the output give me exactly same contain as the input ..
here the example for input.txt :

```
"Nice terrain no MAtter seeing from near or afar morning missing matting cats caresses ponies ties agreed"
```

here main of the porter stem code:

```
public string stem(string word)
{
    if (word.Length < 3) return word;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(word.ToLower());

    if (sb[0] == '\'') sb.Remove(0, 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < exceptions.Length / 2; ++i)
        if (word == exceptions[i, 0])
            return exceptions[i, 1];

        int r1 = 0, r2 = 0;
        changeY(sb);
        computeR1R2(sb, ref r1, ref r2);

        step0(sb);
        step1a(sb);

        for (int i = 0; i < exceptions2.Length; ++i)
            if (sb.ToString() == exceptions2[i])
                return exceptions2[i];

        step1b(sb, r1);
        step1c(sb);
        step2(sb, r1);
        step3(sb, r1, r2);
        step4(sb, r2);
        step5(sb, r1, r2);


        return sb.ToString().ToLower();
}
```

Does anyone know how to complete that code? so i can use it in my final project. thank you.

Comment: Don't you need to split the input string & treat it word by word & then recombine it.

Comment: @PaulF yeah, i have try something like  that by splitting in some delimeter, here the code i use to split the input into word  :

var words = input.Split(_delimiters,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            string word = words.ToString();

and insert ->  sb.Append(currentWord).Append(' '); into the main of porter stemming code but nothing happens ...

Comment: Is it failing due to case-sensitivity on string comparisons?

Comment: Sorry @PaulF, did you mean the 'for' part ? .. yeah i have changes it into foreach too, but nothing changes. if not that part, can you specify about it ? because i don't really get it about what you mean in string comparisons.

Comment: I was talking about case-sensitivity - "Nice" will not be equal to "NICE" or "nice". What you would need to do is convert both to upper or lower case & make the comparison - or better still use the equals method & specify ignore case.

Comment: @PaulF , mmm recently i try to change it using .ToLower before its split away but its got me some error .. so could you give me some example about it ?

Comment: You could try _if (exceptions[i, 0].Equals(word,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))_ and _if (exceptions2[i].Equals(sb.ToString(),StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))_ as your two string comparisons

Comment: @PaulF, i try to insert your example code but nothing changes ... did you have another solution ? Thanks

Comment: This is the code I have run with the class from your original link. _String inputstem =
        "Nice terrain no MAtter seeing from near or afar morning missing matting cats caresses ponies ties agreed";

      Porter2 stemmer = new Porter2();
      String[] ipsStrings = inputstem.Split(' ');
      foreach (var ipsString in ipsStrings)
      {
        String outputstem = stemmer.stem(ipsString);
      }_

Comment: It appears to work correctly, all words are converted to lowercase (I didn't spot that is done in initialisation of sb) and these words are converted see(ing), morn(ing), miss(ing), mat(ting), cat(s), caress(es), poni(es), tie(s), agre(ed) the rest are unchanged. One change I think is needed is the if statement in the first for loop should be _if (sb.ToString() == exceptions[i])_

Comment: sorry @PaulF for bothering you again ..., i try to insert this. //string inputstem = File.ReadAllText(textBox21.Text);  Porter2 stemmer = new Porter2(); String[] ipsStrings = inputstem.Split(' '); foreach (var ipsString {String outputstem = stemmer.stem(ipsString); textBoxfile.Text = outputstem; }. but nothing changes. and i try to pin the code and run it then visual studio show me that outputstem give me 'null' as a result .. so could you maybe help me with the complete answer?. Thanks

Comment: I had to change _foreach (var ipsString_ to _foreach (var ipsString in ipsStrings)_ but otherwise it still works correctly for me. Have you checked that inputstem and ipsStrings do have the expected values in them.

Comment: This is what I have tested : https://dotnetfiddle.net/1KJSw0

Comment: thank you but i have check it, and ipsString get the values input correctly, but when its come to doing stemming in stemmer.stem(ipsString) than the outputstem give 'null'. then i try you code from that link that you hve share to me in winForm. but nothing changes ...

Comment: ahh i think that you're right @PaulF. smething wrong with my input value .. when i changes my input way into this. String inputstem = "Nice terrain no MAtter seeing from near or afar morning missing matting cats caresses ponies ties agreed";. they work for one word 'agre' ... but i don't know how to complete it T.T

Comment: I don't understand the code enough to work out what is happening but _agree_ is correct up to the call to step5 method when the final e is removed. It maybe this method needs changing or the ComputeR1R2 method. Also _ponies_ should be changed to _pony_ and I think _morning_ should be an exception and not be modified.

Comment: about that correction isn't the main concern because when i read at porter stemming documentation's it's exactly the way porter's stemming work on word. the things i want to complete is the way the stemming work on my file. because the programs only give me output when i use the manually input like you do. and it's only give me 1 word..., but Thank you for helping me @PaulF :)

Comment: With your example code _textBoxfile.Text = outputstem;_ the contents of the textbox will be overwritten for each word, so only report the last word. To see all words you would need to append to the textbox - something like : _textBoxfile.Text += ("\r\n" + outputstem);_

Comment: Thank you for your great tips @PaulF :)